# Append clone() elements with other clone() elements

Tags: jquery, append, clone

I am trying to append Clone() elements between new elements that has created with javascript like so:

```
var $user_dp = $(this).parent().parent().find('.dp').clone()
var $user_name = $(this).parent().parent().find('.alias').clone()
var $feed_added = $(this).parent().parent().find('.timeago').clone()
var $feed_status =$(this).parent().parent().find('.feed_status').clone()

$('#pop_up_cont #wrap').html('<div>' + $user_dp + $feed_added + '</div><div>' + $feed_status + '</div>')
```

Im getting `[object Object][object Object][object Object]` rather than elements. [Link](http://devtest23.n0life.com/test.html)  (click on car image)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are appending objects to a string, hence it is implicitly coerced, resulting in a string of `[object Object]`. Instead you need to `append()` the objects individually. Try this:

```
var $container = $(this).parent().parent(); // change to closest()

var $user_dp = $container.find('.dp').clone()
var $user_name = $container.find('.alias').clone()
var $feed_added = $container.find('.timeago').clone()
var $feed_status = $container.find('.feed_status').clone()

$('<div />').append($user_dp, $feed_added).appendTo('#wrap');
$('<div />').append($feed_status).appendTo('#wrap');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you concatenate the strings with the elements, the objects will be converted to strings, and that will just be `"[object Object]"` as there is no special overload of the `toString` method to create HTML code from the elements.

You can create elements that you can append instead of creating a string from elements that will be turned into elements again:

```
var div1 = $('<div>').append([ $user_dp, $feed_added ]);
var div2 = $('<div>').append($feed_status);
$('#pop_up_cont #wrap').empty().append([ div1, div2 ]);
```

Note: If you want to replace the content (as with the `html` method) you would use `empty()` first. If you want to append elements after current content, you would omit the `empty` call.

Answer (score 0):

Because whatever you are getting from `.clone` will be object and not just plaint `html`. So you need to `append` it as below instead of writing it as `html`:

```
$('#pop_up_cont #wrap').append('<div>'+$user_dp+$feed_added+'</div><div>'+$feed_status+'</div>')
```

**UPDATE**

In short and sweet you can finish it in one line as below:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2gx1kxfo/)**

```
$('.cloneb').on('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.dp,.alias,.timeago,.feed_status').clone().appendTo('#pop_up_cont #wrap');
});
```

Comment: You normally can't append object to strings

Comment: I think i tryed with append, same problem

Answer (score 0):

jQuery returns an object, not a string so you cannot concatenate it. Try this:

```
$('#pop_up_cont #wrap')
  .empty()
  .append(
    $('<div/>').append([$user_dp, $feed_added])
    $('<div/>').append($feed_status)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$('#pop_up_cont #wrap').append('<div>'+$user_dp.html()+$feed_added.html()+'</div><div>'+$feed_status.html()+'</div>')
```